# Are there any applications for complex analysis in population dynamics?

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis, soft-question

Strange question: could complex analysis be used to understand population dynamics?

I'm interested in modelling dominance hierarchies, mating relationships, and illness behaviour in ancient populations and am curious if there are any methods within complex analysis that may be useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Analysis, yes! Complex analysis, maybe. Population growth can be well modelled using the exponential function, but usually, no complex numbers appear. And it is doubtful, that group theory helps in such topics.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question, really. How could anyone claim that the methods of complex analysis may not be useful to X, whatever X is? If you asked instead something along the lines of «Have the methods of complex analysis been used in studying population dynamics?» then the situation would be different!

Comment: @Mariano Technically true ... Anyway, do you agree my scepsis ?

Comment: Wow, thank you for responding so quickly!  And thank you for the welcome note, @Peter.  Perhaps I should explain more clearly why I'm asking the question.  I study both applied mathematics and anthropology and am currently taking a complex analysis course.  We are tasked with researching applications of complex analysis, and I'm wondering whether complex has been used within the context of anthropology.  I think it would be fun to combine my two interests for the project.

Comment: So, @Mariano, do you know if methods of complex analysis have been used in studying population dynamics?

Comment: The trouble is that I don't know very much (or anything of value) about complex analysis yet...  Just looking to get a jump-start, really.